# How to convert an array to an object? please

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the following array

```
input : [["A","B"],["C","D"],["F","G"]]
It can be one or two arrays 
    [["A","B"]] or [["A","B"],["C","D"]] or  [["A","B"],["C","D"],["F","G"]]
```

Expected output cartesian:

```
[{"custom1" : "A", "custom2" : "C", "custom3" : "F"},
    {"custom1" : "A", "custom2" : "C", "custom3" : "G"},
    {"custom1" : "A", "custom2" : "D", "custom3" : "F"},
    {"custom1" : "A", "custom2" : "D", "custom3" : "G"},
    {"custom1" : "B", "custom2" : "C", "custom3" : "F"},
    {"custom1" : "B", "custom2" : "C", "custom3" : "G"},
    {"custom1" : "B", "custom2" : "D", "custom3" : "F"},
    {"custom1" : "B", "custom2" : "D", "custom3" : "G"}]

const items = [["A","B"],["C","D"],["F","G"]]
items.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map((w) => [].concat(v, w))), []));
result : [[],[],[].......]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the final result to the object you want.

```
items
  .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map((w) => [].concat(v, w))), []))
  .map((v) => Object.fromEntries(v.map((sv, sk) => [`custom${sk + 1}`, sv])));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this method**

```js
var arr = [["A","B"],["C","D"],["F","G"]];

var obj = Object.assign({}, arr);

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Recursion to achieve this, its more readable.

```
let items = [["A","B"],["C","D"],["E","F"]];
let ans = []

function permutations(index, s) {
  if (index >= items.length) {
    ans.push(s);
    return;
  }
  
  for (let i=0; i < items[index].length; i++){
    permutations(index+1, s+items[index][i]);
  }
}

permutations(0, "");
console.log(ans);
```